# Rejected request when trying to fetch a website contents

Tags: node.js, express, web-scraping, axios

I am writing a small Node.js-based app for webscraping. I am using `axios` library for handling HTTP requests. For some reason, I cannot fetch one website:

```
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  const url = 'http://www.ztm.waw.pl/';
  const fetchRes = await axios.get(url);
  console.log(fetchRes);
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));
```

when I run the server and access http://localhost:3000 I get an error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: write EPROTO 4554425792:error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/statem/statem_lib.c:1922:
```

The code is more or less alright. When I change the `url` to `http://stackoverflow.com` for instance, I get the response.

What is the problem here? I guess that it's something with the request config. I tried to play with it a little bit but with no success.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of the npm packages of the axios? I've tested this code snippet and managed to log the response from this site.

Comment: i think you got a tls problem here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because since Node.js 12, the default TLS settings were tightened. The site doesn't handle TLS v1.2 , but it's required by default in Node.js 12. 
You can change this either via a command line flag (`--tls-min-v1.0`) when starting node, i tested it and it works.   `node --tls-min-v1.0 app.js`